# Regular expression only matches full match and not group

Tags: python, json, regex, findall

I am using re.findall in python to match each line of a log file and extract the json data from that line. Here is an example line:

```
<134>1 2017-01-23T10:54:47.111-01:11 bla blabla  - -  <-- '{"jsondata": "1.0", "result": null, "id": 0}'
```

And the code I'm using on it:

```
 for line in jsonlog:
        json_marker = "<-- '{"
        if json_marker in line:
            #Extract whats between the single quotes on lines where a json is present
            x = re.findall(r"(\'\{(.*?)\}\')", line)
```

That returns this (yes there are two):

```
[('\'{"jsondata": "1.0", "result": null, "id": 0}\'', '"jsondata": "1.0", "result": null, "id": 0')]
```

But I need it to return just the json data from that line in json format :

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": null, "id": 2530}
```

When I put my regex into regex101,

```
\'\{(.*?)\}\'
```

I get a group match for

```
"jsondata": "1.0", "result": null, "id": 0
```

and full match for

```
'{"jsondata": "1.0", "result": null, "id": 0}'
```

So this tells me findall is returning the group. How can I fix this to return the full match, the json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this regular expression:

```
r"({.*?})"
```

This should take all content within the "{ ... }"s

```
log_line = 'sdgfjk fgkglhdfg <-- fdfsd dsdasds {"jsondata": "1.0", "result":  null, "id": 0} dasdsad khfsldfg'

print(re.findall(r"({.*?})", log_line))
```

Here's my output:

```
['{"jsondata": "1.0", "result": null, "id": 0}']
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. I can access the json data by just accessing the list element. Thank you!